# How to add timestamp to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, timestamp

My application has to timestamp files using java. What I'm trying to do is:

1. create a hash of the file
2. send the created hash to a timestamping server
3. add the received timestamp token to the file

I sucessfully developed the first two steps, and now I'm stuck at the third one.

My code for the creation of the hash:

```
    private static byte[] hashFile(File file) throws Exception {

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

    byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
        digest.update(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    byte[] hashed = digest.digest();
    return hashed;
}
```

my code for sending the hash to a timestamping server and receiving a response with a timestamp token:

```
private TimeStampToken sendHash(byte[] hash, String tsa_url) throws Exception {
    TimeStampRequestGenerator reqgen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();

    reqgen.setCertReq(true);

    TimeStampRequest req = reqgen.generate(TSPAlgorithms.SHA256, hash);
    byte[] request = req.getEncoded();

    URL url = new URL(tsa_url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication ("michielvd.20@gmail.com", "TestAccount".toCharArray());
        }
    });
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/timestamp-query");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(request.length));

    OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
    out.write(request);
    out.flush();

    con.getContent();

    if (con.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new IOException("Received HTTP error: " + con.getResponseCode() + " - " + con.getResponseMessage());
    }

    TimeStampResp resp = TimeStampResp.getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(con.getInputStream()).readObject());
    TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);
    response.validate(req);

    TimeStampToken token = response.getTimeStampToken();
    return token;
}
```

Now I would like to add the timestamp token (which the sendHash method returns) to a pdf file and I have no clue about how to do so.
I searched the net but didn't find something useful.

The purpose is to add the token as a signature in pdf, so adobe reader recognises the document as a signed document. I found examples where the timestamp is addes as an addition to a digital signature, but I don't want to sign my document with a signature. I only want the timestamp.

Is there anyone out there who can help me?
(If there's something not clear, please ask)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Er... I understand your requirement, but I don't understand your code. Maybe I am wrong, but when you say that you have to add a Document Timestamp to a PDF, I assume that you are talking about [PAdES part 4 (Long Term Validation)](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_TS/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.01_60/ts_10277804v010101p.pdf), but when I look at your code, I don't see you using any PDF library that supports LTV. Are you sure you weren't assigned to create a Document Time-stamp as described in section A-2 of ETSI TS 102 778-4?

Comment: You may want to read chapter 5 of [this book](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) too. Adding a document time stamp = signing the document. However, adding a document time stamp signature doesn't require that the document is already signed (which is what you're trying to avoid).

Comment: I tried to achieve my goal using libraries such as iText, PDFBox and Aspose (because the application already uses this one). But all of those libraries require a certificate, reason, etc for signing. I think I found 1 decent solution in iText for long term validation, but there I need to establish a new connection with the timestamp server. I can't just create a signature based on my already received token.

Comment: Who says so? The `timestamp()` method in the `LtvTimestamp` class expects an implementation of the `TSAClient` interface. You can write your own custom implementation. For instance: you can make the `getTimeStampToken()` method return whatever you want. Of course: don't expect Adobe Reader to accept whatever your put in the PDF. You need to remain compliant with PAdES-4.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this stuff so I guess I didn't realize that :) Thanks for your help anyway, I'll take a good look at it

Comment: The idea is that the time stamp indicates the time the document was signed, hence it is kind of weird that you wouldn't create the time stamp by connection to the time stamp server at the moment of signing. Maybe you're trying to do something that is impossible... I can't say, your requirement looks like you want a Document Time-stamp as described in PAdES 4, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That's indeed what I'm trying to do and I tried to do it through libraries first, but then the person who gave me this assignment told me to manually create a hash of the file, send this hash to a timestamp server and add the received timestamp to the document.

Comment: *but then the person who gave me this assignment told me to manually create a hash of the file, send this hash to a timestamp server and add the received timestamp to the document.* - That person does not seem to understand how signatures or document time stamps are added to PDF files: First some components are added to the original file for embedding the signature/timestamp, then the hash is calculated for this  changed file (with the exception of a small area reserved for the signature / time stamp), this hash is signed / time stamped, and then the signature / time stamp is embedded.

Comment: Thus, the hashes you make for the original file cannot be used. You may read about the backgrounds [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) and in the documents referenced from there. Document time stamps are created in a similar fashion, cf. [ETSI TS 102 778 part 4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_TS/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.01_60/ts_10277804v010101p.pdf).

Comment: Yep, what @mkl says is what I meant when I wrote that you're trying to do something that is impossible.

Comment: I tried to do it like you said now (with a custom implementation of the TSAClient interface) and it's working :) The only problem I have now is that Adobe tells me that my signature is invalid (I get a red cross), but that' s not the question here, so I'll go for another search on the net :) Thanks for your help!